# How to change Sprite Image when it reaches 90 degrees?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leantween

I say that I am a beginner.

I have a question during the project.

I'm currently implementing a card-matching game.

When I start the game, The image is loaded from the external path (D: / ..).

My question is in the code below.

```
 public void createCardList()
        {
            int count_x = 0;
            int count_y = 0;

            GameObject parent_area = GameObject.Find("GameMain");
            List<int> num = createRandomIndex(createArrayIndex());

            for (int i = 0; i < card_list.Count; ++i)
            {
                if ((i % CARD_ROWS) == 0 && i > 0)
                {
                    count_y += 1;
                    count_x = 0;
                }

                GameObject card_prefab_load = Resources.Load("Prefabs/card") as GameObject;
                GameObject card_prefab_instantiate = Instantiate(card_prefab_load, card_prefab_load.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                float card_position_x = (CARD_WIDTH + CARD_SPACE) * (i % CARD_ROWS) - 290f;
                //Debug.Log("card_position_x" + card_position_x);
                float card_position_y = count_y * (CARD_HEIGHT + CARD_SPACE) - 280f;
                //Debug.Log("card_position_y" + card_position_y);

                card_prefab_instantiate.transform.SetParent(parent_area.transform);
                card_prefab_instantiate.transform.name = "card_" + num[i];
                card_prefab_instantiate.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
                card_prefab_instantiate.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(card_position_x, card_position_y, 1f);

                StartCoroutine(firstRotateOriginalImage());
            }
        }

        // Rotate image
        private IEnumerator firstRotateOriginalImage()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

            GameObject findCardList = GameObject.Find("GameMain");

            for (int i = 0; i < findCardList.transform.childCount; ++i)
            {
                // I don't know what code to put in this part.
            }
        }
```

What I want to implement is below.

1. When the card rotation value reaches 90 degrees,How to change an externally imported image to a Sprite Image of a child GameObject?
2. How to rotate the child objects 360 degrees after the first task is completed?

For example, the picture below.
[image]

Arrows indicate the order in which cards are flipped.
also, Of the 12 GameObjects, Six GameObjects try to implement a common image.

I don't know much. I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that...

1. `transform.Rotate(...)`
2. `transform.RotateAround(...)`
3. `transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles.X|Y|Z +
   amount`
4. `transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation*relativeRotation
   /*= a Quaternion*/`
5. Something else entirely...

Comment: Can you chat with me 1:1?

Comment: Sorry, not atm.

Comment: I want to use the LeanTween Rotation function. Just what I was wondering,

Comment: When you rotate a child GameObject, While the frame is running, check the 90 degrees and add a Sprite Image.

Comment: @최성원 That would just need 2 consecutive rotation loops. First loop rotate 90; between the loops add sprite, and second loop rotates the other 90... --- If you want to do it the hard way, that is... It would be easier to just have the sprite attached from the beginning; unless you're doing something wrong, the sprite should not be visible from the back.

Comment: @AimightyR Are you here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a doubtful regarding how well I understand your question...
But it seems like you want to simply flip the cards over don't you?

The approach I'd take is to have each card as the combination of the face (rotated 180 degrees in Y) and the back, both being children of an empty GameObject.

That way you could simply rotate the Card object using `transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0)`

To use it in a coroutine you could do

```
//Speed of animation (here 0.55 seconds)
float degreesPerSecond = 200f;

//The amount you want to rotate
float maxDegrees = 180f;

//Animate
for (float f = maxDegrees; f < 0;)
{
    //How much to rotate
    float rot = degreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

    //Rotate children
    foreach(var child in transform)
        child.Rotate(0, rot, 0);

    //Record rotation
    f -= rot;

    //Wait next frame
    yield return null;
}

//Round to desired rotation
foreach(var child in transform)
        child.position = new Vector3(child.position.x, maxDegrees, child.position.z);
```

Comment: `transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0)` would do the rotation on a single frame; he seem to want a rotation animation (multiple frames).

Comment: yeah I need that

Comment: you can chat with me 1:1?